# jquery klout hide name value

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, show-hide

I am trying to use jquery to hide my name value on my site using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("iframe#kloutframe").contents().find(".user").hide();
});
```

the klout widget:

```
<div align="center"><iframe name="kloutframe" src="http://widgets.klout.com/badge/chrishough?size=s&text_color=ffffff" style="border:0" scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true" frameBorder="0" width="120px" height="59px"></iframe></div>
```

the frame html outout copied from firebug:

```
<div align="center">
<iframe width="200px" scrolling="no" height="98px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:0" src="http://widgets.klout.com/badge/chrishough?text_color=ffffff" name="kloutframe">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div class="badge_cont">
<a target="_blank" onclick="mpmetrics.track('widgets-badget-click', {'referer':'http://noconformity.co/chrishough/'});" href="http://klout.com/chrishough">
<div class="tile">
<div class="content">
<div class="user">
<div id="klout_name">chrishough</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://static.chartbeat.com/js/chartbeat.js">
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
```

yes, that's a little inline css for centering, but I will be making modifications to that.

for some reason jquery can not find the element to hide it.  thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues so I ended up creating my own badge based on their API.

http://www.kloutwidget.com/

Comment: are you making that publicly accessible for other blogs? I really like bro.  great work.

Comment: yeap, its public and I'll keep it up as long the bills are reasonable.  its cached at many level and is wrapped in a public cache.  you should have no problems with availability

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$("iframe#kloutframe")
```

to

```
$("iframe[name='kloutframe']")
```

also you are aware you wil get 'Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL' unless you have access

Comment: I just changed it to `jQuery("iframe[name='kloutframe']").contents().find(".user").hide();` and unfortunately that did not work :(

Comment: What did not work? Did you get the error i posted about unsafe JavaScript?

Comment: correct, i take that back, i was getting a permissions error.  I have decided to leave the name alone.